# How to parse date in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I must to get properly date value from my long date in string.

I have this date:

```
Sun Aug 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

how to parse this date to: `2020-08-30`?

and i have another use case:

```
Tue Aug 25 2020 11:58:04 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

how to parse this date to: `11:58`?

thanks for any help :)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your strings are always in that format, you could just split on spaces:

```
date = "Sun Aug 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)";
[day_of_week, month, day, year, time, ...tz] = date.split(" ");
tz = tz.join(" "); // combine timezone back into one string
```

You could process this further, but you might want to look more into Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
  const d = new Date(date);
  let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = '' + d.getDate();
  const year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }

  if (day.length < 2) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

// Would print 2020-08-30
console.log(formatDate('Sun Aug 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Date node build in lib or moment. If you’re planning to do a lot of date manipulation I would suggest use moment npm package

For getting the date version

```
   moment(your string).format(“YYYY-MM-DD”)
```

For getting the time

```
   moment(your string).format(“HH:mm”)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

you can use this or if you want to use 3rd party lib moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) is the best and easy to implement
```

Comment: This is very similar to Kousha’s answer. But maybe you both copied it from the same place?